# Not getting any value back from function defined in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my controller. `def random_generate` is not giving me any output, and when I create the object, length is there but `random_primer_generated` is empty. Can someone help me?

```
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  helper_method :random_generate
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def random_generate
    if @generator.choice == 'Randomly'
        length = @generator.primer_length
        chars = 'atgc'
        seq = ''
        #length = length.to_i
        length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
       @generator.random_primer_generated = seq
    end
    return @generator.random_primer_generated
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length, :choice_random_primer_generated)
    end
end
```

This is my Form_VIEW (to get the user's data - length and choice):

```
<%= form_for (@generator ) do |f| %>
  <% if @generator.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@generator.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this generator from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @generator.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <label>Primer Length</label><br>
       <%= f.number_field :primer_length %>
  </div>

    <label>Selection :</label><br>
    <label>Randomly</label>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:choice_random_primer_generated, 'Randomly')%>

<%= button_to('Generate', random_generate_generator_path(@generator))%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Am i doing it wrongly ? I mean my passing method in view button_to ... I'm new to rails T.T

Comment: Just one question: where do you want the method `random_generate` run? Because I don't see you call it anywhere in the above code.

Comment: I want it to run after i click the generate button in my view. It's like user put in their length and their choice - ( now it's only randomly ) then they click generate and they'll get the random generated sequence done by the random_generate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the form may be a red herring here.  If you only want the code to be randomly generated when the user explicitly clicks that button, and NOT after every create or save, then you don't want any callbacks.  You're doing it the right way.  The only thing you are missing is the save call at the end of your method, and you'll also want to redirect the user back to a page.

However, if you DO want generate to happen after EVERY create or update, then you should probably change that button_to call to f.submit, and move that random_generate code to your model.  Then, you can use rails callback for after_save and call that method from there within your controller.

More info:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: erm when u say  NOT after every create or save, what do you mean ? What if i have 3 different choice of generating. FIRST IS BY RANDOM ( the above method ) 2nd n 3rd are another method [ USER's choice as in how they wan to generate the result ]. Can i still put the function in the model ? If so how should i call the method from my VIEW

Comment: If you add callbacks, those callback will be run every time the method they are attached to is called.  Thus, if you attach a callback of any sort (either in the controller using after_actions, or in the model using after_save), then that generator will generate each time.  If you don't want this behavior, then you want code closer to your original post -- having a method that the user would explicitly hit to run the generation process.  If you want more generation methods than random, simply add more buttons and methods.

Comment: hi GoGoCarl : When u said ' if you attach a callback of any sort (either in the controller using after_actions, or in the model using after_save), then that generator will generate each time.' do you mean the helper_method ? what if i have 2 more method to define in my controller. Will all those 3 be triggered even though im just calling 1 of them in my view ?

Comment: If you use a callback in the controller, it's triggered for every method unless you specify otherwise (via :only/:except options). Again, the need for callbacks depends on your use case. It sounds like you probably want to consider using the active record callbacks I mentioned in my earlier comment. I'd recommend using before_save instead of after_save, though, such that the order of events would be 1) user saves changes to generator 2) controller create/update method runs, 3) in before_save handling method, check choice option (randomly, etc) & run appropriate generator 4) save happens, done.

Comment: if i declare the method random_generate in my model class , how should i call them from my view ?

Comment: Using the ActiveRecord callbacks I referenced earlier.  Button in view goes to the Controller method.  When that method calls generator.save, it's eventually going to check for a before_save handler, which you should set up to call a method like doGenerate (i.e. before_save :doGenerate).  So, you wouldn't directly call the method, it would just be called whenever a save happens, after form validations complete, and just before data is written to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your helper_method anywhere. When you post the form and it reaches the server, the create method is called. The helper_method is not triggered, therefore you are not creating a random number.

I didn't understand it very well, but what are you trying to randomize? Why don't you simply use a rand(999) to randomize numbers for example?

Comment: I'm trying to randomize a short sequence. for example ATTGAGCT ( generate according to the length user give me) . What do you mean the helper_method is not triggered ? How do i fix it ? SOrry for the trouble T.T

Comment: the guy below showed you an example to fix it. Just add an after_create callback.

Comment: @BrianChoo What @renatojf means when he says `helper_method is not triggered` is that you never execute or run `helper_method`. You have defined what the method is supposed to do, but you never actually tell your app to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to call `random_generate` after your new and create action, but you are not calling it. All you have to do is change `helper_method :random_generate` to `after_action :random_generate, only: [:create, :new]`

You also want to make sure to save your new record in `random_generate`. You don't need the `return @genator.random_primer_generated`. See below:

```
def random_generate
  if @generator.choice == 'Randomly'
    length = @generator.primer_length
    chars = 'atgc'
    seq = ''
    #length = length.to_i
    length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
   @generator.random_primer_generated = seq
  end
  @generator.save!
end
```

Comment: Huy : I followed your steps but after clicking Generate , only the Length shows me a value.The random primer generated is still empty T.T ....

Comment: @BrianChoo I think I know what you're trying to do now. It seems like you want to call `random_generate` when you press the `Generate` button. The generate button should call the `create` action which will create a new Generator record. The `after_action` will then call `random_generate` which will update your new record, `@generator`, with the `random_primer_generated`. I updated my answer to include a @generator.save in your `random_generate` method.

Comment: :THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! it works now ... but could you tell me why do i need a save ? because in Ruby we just have to return value to the attribute and they're fine but in Rails it's so complicated T.T ... THANKS FOR SAVING ME ... It's my final year project... and this is just 1 of the function to get sequence. I still need to define 2 more T.T ...

Comment: No problem @BrianChoo. Glad to have been able to help. Please accept my answer if it helped you :). Returning the value does not actually save the value. You want to save for the value to persist in the database.

Comment: there seems to be a problem :( ... Whenever i want to cr8 a new object, it creates 2 OBJECTS ... 1 with totally NULL for both attributes - LENGTH and RANDOM PRIMER GENERATED and the other object has the attribute i entered. Does it has anything to do with the button_to ?